# Is it possible to make a column chart to add new data point always with animation?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There is a array of data which I would like to add to a bar chart one by one.

As shown in this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q3nLsdg/12/)

The part associated with adding point per clicking a buttion is:

```
$('#b').click(function(){
    timeStamps.push(new Date()); //record the current timestamp
    var buttonB =  document.getElementById('b');
    buttonB.disabled = false; //disable the button
    if(index <= chartData.length){
            if(index==1){
                chart2.series[0].addPoint([index, chartData[index - 1]],true, false);
                index++;                      
            }else{
                chart2.series[0].addPoint([index, chartData[index - 1]],true, false);
                index++;      
            }
     }

}
```

When the first bar is added, the chart takes a while to draw the column; when the second bar is added, the chart draws the column immediately. Is there any way to make sure every data point is added to the chart with animation? (instead of only the first one?)

Comment: `buttonB.disabled = false;` makes the button **not** be disabled.

Comment: Also in that `if/else` statement the `if` part and the `else` part are identical O.o

Comment: Updated, http://jsfiddle.net/6q3nLsdg/12/  Problem persists. The identical if and else is for demonstration purpose.

Comment: @JohnM The point of this question is to have the bar animation happen for subsequently added chart points; your answer on the other question doesn't address that.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Issue here is about animation. How about adding 0-value point and then updating it? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6q3nLsdg/13/

Comment: @PawełFus Thank you. Why `index - 1` in `chart2.series[0].data[index - 1]` instead of `index`? Is that because it start at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: That's right, your index starts from 1, but when you use `addPoint()` then points are added to `chart.series[0].data` array where index starts from 0.